# System.Design/ClassComments1 conflicts in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a strange error, it says System.Design/ClassComments1 conlicts , but I don't find what's wrong. Where can I find this system.design, or solve the error?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details? A [mcve] would be better. With only error messages, it's hard to say why you have this problem.

Comment: Look in your UWP project obj folder for System.Design.resw. In my case, I have two duplicates, creating the conflict. I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: I just can't use Bitmap in the project. Bitmap needs a using that is forbidden in UWP, but visual studio don't tell it to me...